# jQuery UI Autocomplete value disappears when selected in IE

Tags: c#, .net, jquery-ui, rad-controls

I have a RadTextBox that is using the jQuery UI autocomplete feature for specific values. This works great in Firefox & Chrome but when I go to select an item from the autocomplete values it does not fill the value in IE 9. Unsure why it doesn't work or what I need to do to make it work.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
   "ActionScript",
   "AppleScript",
   "Asp",
   "BASIC",
   "C",
   "C++",
   "Clojure",
   "COBOL",
   "ColdFusion",
   "Erlang",
   "Fortran",
   "Groovy",
   "Haskell",
   "Java",
   "JavaScript",
   "Lisp",
   "Perl",
   "PHP",
   "Python",
   "Ruby",
   "Scala",
   "Scheme"
  ];
            $(".riTextBox").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });

       
    </script>`

Comment: `<telerik:RadTextBox AutoCompleteType="Search" columns="25" ID="nihSearch" runat="server" CssClass="homeSearchBox" EmptyMessageStyle-CssClass="empty" EmptyMessage="Add Keywords...">
                                </telerik:RadTextBox>`

Comment: riTextBox is the class that shows up when the html is rendered.